# Is it possible to run a core PHP project in Laravel project 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have a central system developed in Laravel 8, which manages user details, companies, and various other data. Additionally, there are separate PHP projects on different domains that handle company projects and quotations. The main Laravel project serves as a central hub, containing all user information. The other systems retrieve user details from the main project via an API.

Now, I am planning to integrate all these projects together. Here's how it should look:

**Main Project**
laravel-project.com

**2nd Project**
laravel-project.com/second-project

**3rd Project**
laravel-project.com/third-project

I want to implement an administration panel to manage permissions for staff members, determining who can access each of these systems.

Please feel free to point out any errors in this question. This is my first time asking a question here.

I attempted to run the projects within the "public" folder, but I encountered issues due to class not found errors in that location.

Comment: The public directory must be the project root. Your other subproject's public dir must also be public, which is only possible with url rewrites. Why not use subdomains? Which makes it way easier to implement. Your laravel routes are also not affected in the future if you use subdomains.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the specific issue you want to ask about including relevant code and exact error messages, and any necessary test data. You asked for feedback...the main issue with your question is it's far too vague and there is no concrete problem for anyone to solve.

Comment: @Leroy, I'd like to centralize user sessions across multiple subsystems by enabling users to log in through the main system. Once a user logs in, their session data should be accessible and synchronized across all sub-systems. This is why I prefer to have a single domain for this functionality.

Comment: oh it's not safe to share session data between applications. You can manipulate session data of another application if you are not carefull. You might want to consider using a mechanism that's specifically designed for that like OAuth2, OpenID Connect (OIDC) or SAML.  But if you really want to rely on sharing session data, the PHPSESSID can be shared accross subdomains by setting the `session.cookie_domain` in php.ini or using `ini_set`.

Comment: thanks, @Leroy, I will try this method